# How to filter item from array in React if their length is less than a certain number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, methods, filter

I'm trying to use the **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method to filter out items from an array, if the **array's length** is less than a certain number, in **[Reactjs](https://en.reactjs.org/)**. I haven't been able to accomplish this so far.

**Code Sample:**

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        itemNumber: 2,
        items: [
        { text: "Item 1" },
        { text: "Item 2" },
        { text: "Item 3" },
        { text: "Item 4" }
      ]
    }
  }

  filterItem = () => {
    if ( this.state.items.length > this.state.itemNumber ) {

        console.log('Items length is higher');

      let newItems = this.state.items.filter(item => {
        return item < this.state.itemNumber;
      });

      console.log(newItems);

    } else {

      console.log('Items length is lower');

    }
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        { this.state.items.map(item => 
          (
            <li key={item.id}>
              { item.text }
            </li>
          )
        )}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.filterItem}>Filter items!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/Lwujxdqg/49/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never `setting` the `state`

```
 filterItem = () => {
    if ( this.state.items.length > this.state.itemNumber ) {

        console.log('Items length is higher');

      let newItems = this.state.items.filter((item,i) => {
        return i < this.state.itemNumber;
      });

      this.setState({items: newItems})

      console.log(newItems);

    } else {

      console.log('Items length is lower');

    }
  };
```

Comment: On filter this will not print anything on screen because of `item < this.state.itemNumber`. try to use `index`.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal, map takes second argument as `index`, you need to use that `this.state.items.filter((item,index) => {
        return index < this.state.itemNumber;
      })`.

Comment: Yeap. My bad, updated to reflect the changes proposed by @ravibagul91

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but can't you just use slice?

```
const newItems = [...this.state.items].slice(0, this.state.itemNumber).map(item =>
```

Comment: `splice` will actually mutate the state. This is bad advice

Comment: Not if you do it in render

Comment: Even in render. `this.state.items.splice` will mutate the state

Answer (score 1):

Just as @Dupocas said, you never update your state.
You need to use `this.setState` to update React component's state.

I think you should have 2 kinds of array in your states

```
this.state = {
    itemNumber: 2,
    items: [
       { text: "Item 1" },
       { text: "Item 2" },
       { text: "Item 3" },
       { text: "Item 4" }
    ],
    filteredItems: [],
}
```

Then you should modify the filter function like this:

```
filterItem = () => {
  if ( this.state.items.length > this.state.itemNumber ) {

      console.log('Items length is higher');

      let newItems = this.state.items.filter((item, index) => {
        return index < this.state.itemNumber;
      });

      console.log(newItems);
      this.setState({filteredItems: newItems});

  } else {

      console.log('Items length is lower');

  }
}
```

Notice the `this.setState({filteredItems: newItems});` line, this line will update `this.state.filteredItems`.

Finally, in the render function:

```
render() {
const { filteredItems } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
    { filteredItems.map(item => 
      (
        <li key={item.id}>
          { item.text }
        </li>
      )
    )}
    </ul>
    <button onClick={this.filterItem}>Filter items!</button>
  </div>
)
}
```

This will render an empty array until the filter button is clicked.
To display the complete array on first time render, add this function to the component

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({filteredItems: [ ...this.state.items ]});
}
```

In case somebody is asking what does the `[ ...this.state.items ]` do, it's called [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

use **filter** to filter an array,

```
let arr = ["item1", "item12", "item123"];
arr = arr.filter((item) => item.length >= 6)); //6 is the min length of item that you want.
```

It will return the new array with the filtered result.

You can declare any other array and store the result in that also
like

```
let arr = ["item1", "item12", "item123"];
let arr1 = arr.filter((item) => item.length >= 6));
```